# What is meaning of LAB-n in LAB TF

Tags: apache-camel, hl7, jbossfuse, hapi, hl7-v2

Currently we are working on Laboratory domain.
The Laboratory domain embraces many profiles and each profiles consist of lots of actors.
Where  [LAB TF](http://www.ihe.net/uploadedFiles/Documents/Laboratory/IHE_LAB_TF_Vol2a.pdf) mentioned **LAB**-n several times.

In example:

1. LAB-1~5  **(5)**
2. LAB-21~23 **(3)**
3. LAB-26~31  **(6)**
4. LAB-51  **(1)**
5. LAB-61~62 **(2)**

---

What are they actually?
Machine, Device, Actor or anything else?
What are they use for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where is the correct dictionary-style definition and I failed to find one on the [www.ihe.net](http://www.ihe.net/) website, but my translation is:

they are actually **transaction identifiers**.

Some short sequences of letters and digits uniquely identifying the "process/scenario/sequence of events/unit of change/use case/.." you are talking about.

A patient came to the doctor, a nurse took his blood sample and send it to the laboratory in order to diagnose what kind of bad-specimens live in there. After some time of analyzing and cultivation the results are know, travel back to the doctor, who then picks a diagnosis and proposes a treatment.

This flow of events can be described as sequence of `transactions`. The details may vary, but the concepts are approximately the same, regardless of the country, town, hospital, gender. Uniquely identified "steps" where the actors are typically mapped to (or supported by) communicating software components. The more compatible the "steps" or `transactions` are the easier it is to integrate equipment, people, software coming from different cultures or vendors. `IHE` attempts to identify those patterns and give them names - transaction identifiers

For instance `LAB-26` describes (my interpretation) what happens when the analyzer device (called "(LD)Pre/PostAnalyzer") detects a specimen and needs to send notification to the automatic test scheduler (software component called "Automation Manager") saying that the result is known and can be further processed, e.g. that laboratory worker can take the sample tubes out of the machine and insert another set and the laboratory doctor can schedule another (refining) set of tests for this sample

See also:

- chapter "2.2 The generic IHE Transaction Model" in your document